# Margin / Spacing of QLayout when using OS Scaling

Tags: windows, qt, qt5

Is there a possibility, that the margin / spacing of layouts scale in a qt application when using a scale factor (like in Windows)?

For example: I have a QGridLayout with several Widgets in it. The spacing between the Widgets is always the same pixel size, it does not (like fonts) scale when I set the scale factor in Windows to 200%.

Tested in Windows 10 and Qt 5.9

Comment: Isn't it because spacing measured in pixels but scaling changes DPI? So that scaling doesn't affect spacing.

Comment: I guess so, but that's very annoying, i cannot set a spacing that looks good on both: ldpi devices with 100% and hdpi devices with >100%

Comment: I think you have to recalculate new spacing and update all layouts.

Comment: thanks, but that is the worst case scenario, I hoped that there is some easier way to fix it. I've already tried style sheets (because they accept values with em) but its not possible to set a style sheet for a layout

Comment: I second this. I'm struggling badly with this exact same issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I ended up using QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling) and QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps) (for nice icons). I program everything for low dpi and Qt handles scaling completely. Some items do not look very good on high dpi screens but that can be fixed with a style sheet

Comment: Struggling with this too; cannot set application-wide scaling, as my program runs as a guest within an embedded Python interpreter (PyQt, PySide) within a larger application.